# How to do { <S-exp> }?

Tags: c++, scheme, ebnf

I'm going to check whether the input is correct.

This is syntax:

```
<S-exp> ::= <ATOM> 
            | LEFT-PAREN <S-exp> { <S-exp> } [ DOT <S-exp> ] RIGHT-PAREN
            | QUOTE <S-exp>
            
<ATOM>  ::= SYMBOL | INT | FLOAT | STRING 
            | NIL | T | LEFT-PAREN | RIGHT-PAREN
```

I write the code based on the syntax, but I don't know how to do `{<S-exp}`

I tried it too many times, but my code still not correct.

My Code:

```
bool Atom( vector<TokenList> token, int i ) {
    return (token[i].type == "SYMBOL" || token[i].type == "INT" || token[i].type == "FLOAT" || token[i].type == "STRING" ||
        token[i].type == "NIL" || token[i].type == "T" || token[i].type == "LEFT_PAREN" || token[i].type == "RIGHT_PAREN");
} // Atom()

bool check = false;
bool Sexp(vector<TokenList> token, int i) {
    if (token[i].type == "LEFT_PAREN") {
        i++;
        if (Sexp(token, i)) {
               // How to do { <S-exp> } ?
        } // if
        else return false;
        
        i++;
        if (token[i].type == "DOT") {
            i++;
            check = Sexp(token, i);
            if (check == false)
                return false;
        } // if
        
        if (token[i].data == ")")
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    } // if
    
    else if (token[i].type == "QUOTE") {
        i++;
        return Sexp(token, i);
    } // else if
    

    else if (Atom(token, i)) {
        return true;
    } // if
    else return false;
} // Sexp()
```

Comment: The tags are not very helpful, look at the tag descriptions. What `{ <S-exp> }` means depends on the variation of the syntax notation you use. I assume you are using [tag:ebnf]?

Comment: @asynts That's right. I use ebnf.

Comment: general style comment: In C++ we'd typically use an `enum` for `type`, where you currently use a string like `"LEFT_PAREN"`.

Comment: I would recommend that you not modify `i`, but use `i+1`, `i+2`, ... Mutable state is tricky. (And keep an eye on the size of the vector.)

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption seems to be rooted in `Sexp(token, i)`. It appears that your test is whether `token[i]` by itself is an S-exp? But that's not what the grammar says: an `S-exp` can be more than one token.

It might be that I misinterpret your meaning of `Sexp(token,i)`. Another interpretation would be "does a S-exp token start at `token[i]`"? This is a reasonable question, but usually that question has a second part: "if so, then what is the end position `j` ?". You just return a `bool`, so that's not how I read your code.